Why is it that an HTML file opened via symlink ignores CSS?
I just downloaded a website using wget and made a symlink of one of the articles as a reminder for later reading, and when this symlink is opened, I only get a bare bones version of the page, but if it's opened from the actual file, I get the proper version of the page.

is it a symlink and not a hardlink? What exactly is in the <link> element in the HTML?

There are 3 likely possibilities:

You did not download all the files required to properly style the page.  You may need to download additional CSS or JavaScript files, which may originate from the same, or different, hosts.
You only symlinked the main HTML file, but not the files called by the main HTML, including CSS (and possibly JavaScript) files.  Thus, the main HTML file to which you symlinked cannot find the CSS (and possibly JS) file(s) needed to format the website.
Because you downloaded the file, you may have different permissions for downloaded files than for HTML files viewed online.  If the HTML file calls JavaScript that then loads CSS, and the system isn't configured to allow this functionality for locally downloaded HTML files (such restrictions are advised in many situation), then the article will not be properly formatted.

My recommendation is to focus on CSS files, as that is most likely the issue.  Ensure the requisite CSS files are downloaded and that the HTML file points to a location at which it can access them.

Because the HTML file contains a link to the CSS file(s), and that link is relative to the location of the HTML file. The browser tries to follow the link and there's nothing there.
For example you downloaded a website to ~/Downloads/site/. This contains an HTML file ~/Downloads/site/index.html with a link to style/foo.css. When you open index.html in the browser, it reads the link to the CSS and knows to look in ~/Downloads/site/style/foo.css.
However, if you made a link from ~/bookmarks/oct/index.html to ~/Downloads/site/index.html, when you open that in the browser, the browser will see the relative link to style/foo.css and try to open ~/bookmarks/oct/style/foo.css, which doesn't exist.
